# org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

Here i am trying to create table using hbase. Here org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException  will appear.

```
 HBaseConfiguration hbaseConfiguration = new HBaseConfiguration(new Configuration());    
  HTableDescriptor htable = new HTableDescriptor("Test");
  htable.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Id"));
  htable.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("Name"));       

  HBaseAdmin hbaseAdmin = new HBaseAdmin(hbaseConfiguration);            
  hbaseAdmin.createTable(htable);
```

Comment: In which mode are you running standalone or cluster ?
Were you able to create hbase tables from hbase shell ?

Comment: yes. i created hbase table from hbase shell. Cluster mode. But codingwise cannot be created.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to create hbase tables from hbase shell then hbase is running good, You got to modify your code by by specifying zookeeper quorum in the code.

```
Configuration hbaseConfiguration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
hbaseConfiguration.addResource("<HBASE_CONF_DIR_PATH>/hbase-site.xml");
```

or

```
Configuration hbaseConfiguration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
hbaseConfiguration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","<ZK-QUORUM>");
```

Comment: I am using above zookeeper quorum and hbase configuration directory path. but not working . I got same exception.